# Statement couldn't be executed, please retry: oracle.kv.FaultException: no such object in table (12.1.4.3.11) (18.3.10)

Tags: java, database, exception, rmi, oracle-nosql

I am using a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) container that contains Oracle NoSQL Database. I am trying to create a table and fill up some records using a Java program.

The data I am trying to store is metadata from a tweet stored in a JSON file, but for the sake of simplicity I have prepared a demo with a much more basic example. In this demo, what I'll try to do is create and fill up a table with only 4 fields and a very simple JSON file with the data to stored. Here is the code:

```
private static void demo(KVStore kvstore, String file2load) {
    //Creating the table
    String query = "CREATE TABLE Carros (plate STRING, brand STRING, owner STRING, km NUMBER, primary key (plate))";
    try {
        kvstore.executeSync(query);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid statement:\n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (FaultException e) { //ATENTION HERE <-
        System.out.println("Statement couldn't be executed, please retry: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Table created");
    //Fill up the table
    populateTable(kvstore, file2load);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

What you see above is the method called in main. Now, I will also leave the method populateTable() down here, although it works fine:

```
private static void populateTable(KVStore kvstore, String file2load) {
    TableAPI tableH = kvstore.getTableAPI();
    Table myTable = tableH.getTable("Carros");

    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;

    try {
        String jObj = "";
        String currLine;
        int tCount = 0;
        boolean buildObj = false;
        boolean beganParsing = false;

        fr = new FileReader(file2load);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tCount += countParens(currLine, '{'); 

            if ((currLine = br.readLine()) == "\n") {
                continue;
            }

            if (tCount > 0) {
                buildObj = true;
                beganParsing = true;
            }
            //Anadimos la linea leida
            if (buildObj) {
                jObj += currLine;
            }

            tCount -= countParens(currLine, '}');
            if (tCount < 1)
                buildObj = false;


            if (beganParsing && !buildObj) {
                Row row = myTable.createRowFromJson(jObj, false);
                tableH.put(row, null, null);
                jObj = "";
            }
        }//While

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + fnfe);
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe);
        System.exit(-1);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            System.out.println("IOException on close: " + iox);
        }
    }
}//populateTable
```

So my problem here is that, every single time I have executed this program, it reaches end of the execution without problems, because I use try-catch blocks, however, it doesn't create nor fill up any table. The message I'm getting is:

> Statement couldn't be executed, please retry: oracle.kv.FaultException: no such object in table (12.1.4.3.11) (18.3.10)
>   Fault class name: oracle.kv.impl.admin.AdminFaultException

I have commented the exception that causes this in the first piece of code above. Since I didn't find any success searching this problem, I removed the try-catch to get a more detailed error trace:

> Exception in thread "main" oracle.kv.FaultException: no such object in table (12.1.4.3.11) (18.3.10)
>   Fault class name: oracle.kv.impl.admin.AdminFaultException
>           at oracle.kv.impl.client.admin.DdlStatementExecutor.executeDdl(DdlStatementExecutor.java:400)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.api.KVStoreImpl.executeDdl(KVStoreImpl.java:3242)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.api.KVStoreImpl.execute(KVStoreImpl.java:3157)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.api.KVStoreImpl.executeSync(KVStoreImpl.java:3328)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.api.KVStoreImpl.executeSync(KVStoreImpl.java:3321)
>           at writer_v01.demo(writer_v01.java:267)
>           at writer_v01.main(writer_v01.java:51)
>   Caused by: no such object in table (12.1.4.3.11) java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
>           at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
>           at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
>           at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getSerialVersion(Unknown Source)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.util.registry.RemoteAPI.(RemoteAPI.java:40)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.sna.StorageNodeAgentAPI.(StorageNodeAgentAPI.java:95)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.sna.StorageNodeAgentAPI.wrap(StorageNodeAgentAPI.java:104)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.util.registry.RegistryUtils.getStorageNodeAgent(RegistryUtils.java:577)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.Admin.getSNStatus(Admin.java:3973)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.Admin.getSNsVersion(Admin.java:3938)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.Admin.getStoreVersion(Admin.java:3781)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.plan.TablePlanGenerator.checkStoreVersion(TablePlanGenerator.java:122)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.plan.TablePlanGenerator.createAddTablePlan(TablePlanGenerator.java:100)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.plan.Planner.createAddTablePlan(Planner.java:493)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.TableDdlOperation$CreateTable.perform(TableDdlOperation.java:97)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.DdlHandler$DdlOperationExecutor.execute(DdlHandler.java:645)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.DdlHandler.handleResults(DdlHandler.java:293)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.DdlHandler.(DdlHandler.java:105)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.Admin.executeStatement(Admin.java:4488)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.ClientAdminServiceImpl$1.execute(ClientAdminServiceImpl.java:65)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.ClientAdminServiceImpl$1.execute(ClientAdminServiceImpl.java:62)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.fault.ProcessFaultHandler.execute(ProcessFaultHandler.java:118)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.ClientAdminServiceImpl.execute(ClientAdminServiceImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.MethodHandlerUtils.invokeMethod(MethodHandlerUtils.java:44)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.SecureProxy$CheckingHandler.invoke(SecureProxy.java:559)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.SecureProxy.invoke(SecureProxy.java:114)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.Admin.getSNStatus(Admin.java:3975)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.Admin.getSNsVersion(Admin.java:3938)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.Admin.getStoreVersion(Admin.java:3781)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.plan.TablePlanGenerator.checkStoreVersion(TablePlanGenerator.java:122)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.plan.TablePlanGenerator.createAddTablePlan(TablePlanGenerator.java:100)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.plan.Planner.createAddTablePlan(Planner.java:493)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.TableDdlOperation$CreateTable.perform(TableDdlOperation.java:97)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.DdlHandler$DdlOperationExecutor.execute(DdlHandler.java:645)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.DdlHandler.handleResults(DdlHandler.java:293)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.DdlHandler.(DdlHandler.java:105)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.Admin.executeStatement(Admin.java:4488)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.ClientAdminServiceImpl$1.execute(ClientAdminServiceImpl.java:65)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.ClientAdminServiceImpl$1.execute(ClientAdminServiceImpl.java:62)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.fault.ProcessFaultHandler.execute(ProcessFaultHandler.java:118)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.admin.ClientAdminServiceImpl.execute(ClientAdminServiceImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.MethodHandlerUtils.invokeMethod(MethodHandlerUtils.java:44)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.SecureProxy$CheckingHandler.invoke(SecureProxy.java:559)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.SecureProxy.invoke(SecureProxy.java:114)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
>           at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
>           at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.MethodHandlerUtils.invokeMethod(MethodHandlerUtils.java:44)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.ContextProxy$ContextMethodHandler.invoke(ContextProxy.java:197)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.security.ContextProxy.invoke(ContextProxy.java:61)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.client.admin.ClientAdminServiceAPI.execute(ClientAdminServiceAPI.java:111)
>           at oracle.kv.impl.client.admin.DdlStatementExecutor.executeDdl(DdlStatementExecutor.java:363)
>           ... 6 more
>   I have been searching for days on why this doesn't work. Moreover, I can't even perform operations on the kv terminal like

```
execute "CREATE TABLE ....."
```

Because it wouldn't work either. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This exception means that you are using a stale stub, i.e. the stub of a remote object that has been unexported since you acquired it. How this can happen within this framework is a mystery. You should report this as a bug to Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem gets solved when introducing the *query* variable declaration inside the try block; in other words:

```
private static void demo(KVStore kvstore, String file2load) {
//Creating the table
String query;
try {
query = "CREATE TABLE Carros (plate STRING, brand STRING, owner STRING, km NUMBER, primary key (plate))";
    kvstore.executeSync(query);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid statement:\n" + e.getMessage());
} catch (FaultException e) { //ATENTION HERE <-
    System.out.println("Statement couldn't be executed, please retry: " + e);
}
System.out.println("Table created");
//Fill up the table
populateTable(kvstore, file2load);
System.exit(0);
}
```

However, if you perform the command:

> execute "SELECT * FROM Carros"

will return to you 0 rows, BUT, if you see the table through SQLDeveloper, you'll see that it is created correctly and also contains the data introduced with the JSON file. I have come to the conclusion that this is, indeed, a bug.

I recommend to anyone having the same problem what @user207421 said in his comment, to open an Oracle Bug Report.

Comment: I am sorry but your solution doesn't seem right to me. To me, this looks like an intermittent issue that got resolved when you attempted next time..